# How to solve A*X - X*A' = 0

Tags: matlab, math, linear-algebra

I have an equation of the form `A*X = X*A'`, where A and X are real, square matrices (3x3 in that case) and A is known and A' represent the transpose of A.  How to solve for X using MATLAB? (up to a scale factor)

Comment: do you want to write code for it or just trying to solve it?

Comment: write code to solve it I guess...

Answer (score 4):

This is a [Sylvester equation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sylvester.html). However, it is singular because the eigenvalues of A and A' are the same. But you can use the formulae 
[I⊗A-A'⊗I]X(:)=C(:):

```
m=kron(eye(3),a)+kron(-a,eye(3))
v=null(m)
x1=reshape(v(:,1),[3 3])
x2=reshape(v(:,2),[3 3]) 
x3=reshape(v(:,3),[3 3])
```

Now the solution is span{x1,x2,x2}, i.e. any matrix of the form
b x1 + c x2 +d x3, where b,c,d are any real numbers

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Matlab has facilities for symbolic algebra.

If you expand A and X, and work through the expression, you obtain an 3x3 matrix with equation in several unknowns, all of which are zero. You then solve that.

But I don't think Matlab allows you to set a matrix to a symbol, rather than an value and expand it for you. For this simple case, you could easily write such a function, that multiples a string matrix by a numerical matrix. The snag is it's hard to scale it up to the general case without throwing the entire Maple / Mathematica engine at it.

Comment: thanks that's not a bad suggestion although I was hoping for something a bit simpler :)

Comment: Matlab should come with MuPAD built in, symbolic math engine, though in earlier versions you had to start it up as a separate program, and it should be able to solve symbolically the given equation.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen MuPAD is not built in, it is a separate toolbox that you have to buy the license for.